# Entity Framework Poor Performance

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVb4i.png)

Am using EF 6.1.1 in C# Windows Forms Application and facing strange issues on Performance factor.

My database has a table with name `Ticket` and has 49300 records. This table has multiple other tables linked. Entity Framework diagram is available at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lgyb.png

The record counts are as follows:

```
BillableOption  4  
Company 390  
Contact 687  
Location    3  
Member  16  
ServiceBoard    6  
ServiceItem 0  
ServicePriority 8  
ServiceSource   5  
ServiceStatus   93  
ServiceSubType  668  
ServiceType 20  
Ticket  49300  
TimeEntry   52518  
TimeEntryMember 0  
WorkRole    10  
WorkType    5
```

My EF Data Context is globally available as a static variable of a class. When I fire following code, it takes **12-15 seconds to load data (only talking about `.ToList()` method).** and bind with DataGridView. Is there any way to increase the performance?

```
    public static List LoadTicket()
    {
        bool lastValue1 = DataAccessLocal.dc.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;
        bool lastValue2 = DataAccessLocal.dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
        DataAccessLocal.dc.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        DataAccessLocal.dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var returnValue = (from r in DataAccessLocal.dc.Tickets.AsNoTracking()
                           select new LinqTicket
                           {
                               Summary = r.Summary,
                               DetailDescription = r.Summary,
                               Resolution = r.Resolution,
                               CompanyName = r.Company.CompanyName,
                               ContactName = (r.Contact == null ? string.Empty : r.Contact.FirstName + " " + r.Contact.LastName),
                               BoardName = r.ServiceBoard.ServiceBoardName,
                               Priority = r.ServicePriority.ServicePriorityName,
                               Source = r.ServiceSource.ServiceSourceName,
                               Location = r.Location.LocationName,
                               ServiceType = r.ServiceTypeRecId == null ? string.Empty : r.ServiceType.ServiceTypeName,
                               ServiceSubType = r.ServiceSubTypeRecId == null ? string.Empty : r.ServiceSubType.ServiceSubTypeName,
                               ServiceItem = r.ServiceItemRecId == null ? string.Empty : r.ServiceItem.ServiceItemText,
                               StatusName = r.ServiceStatus.ServiceStatusName,
                               TicketRecId = r.TicketRecId,
                               RemoteTicketId = r.RemoteTicketRecId.Value,
                               DueDate = r.RequiredDate == null ? new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) : r.RequiredDate.Value,
                               EstimatedHours = r.BudgetHours == null ? 0 : r.BudgetHours.Value,
                               ServiceBoardId = r.ServiceBoard.ServiceBoardRecId,
                               InternalStatus = r.InternalStatus.HasValue == true ? (enmInternalStatus)r.InternalStatus.Value : enmInternalStatus.OK,
                               LastUpdatedByMemberRecId = r.LastUpdatedByMemberRecId
                           }).ToList();

        DataAccessLocal.dc.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = lastValue1;
        DataAccessLocal.dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = lastValue2;
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to bind that many records to the DataGridView, you should use [Virtual Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd28yf6d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Quote from msdn [Implementing Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.110).aspx):

> One reason to implement virtual mode in the DataGridView control is to retrieve data only as it is needed. This is called *just-in-time data loading*.

Comment: Max amount of time is taken in .ToList() method.

Comment: @SanketShah, with virtual mode that will not be a problem, because data is only retrieved as it is needed. All the records are not retrieved at once.

Comment: Any samples in relation with EF 6? Am using `DbContext` approach.

Comment: @SanketShah, No, I do not have any samples that use DataGridView in virtual mode with EF6.